# Make jquery plugin by function in result

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin.

```
$.fn.examplePlugin = function(callback) {
    $.item = $(this);
    $(this).hide('fast',function () {
        callback('bla');
    });

    function show(a) {
       alert(a);
    }    

}
```

and use

```
$('form').examplePlugin(function(data)) {
    this.show(data); // need to return alert 'bla'
});
```

need to return alert 'bla'

Comment: What do you think the code `$.item = $(this);` does? Because it's a *really bad idea*. For that matter, why do you think the return value of the callback you pass to `hide` is used for anything? Have you read the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com)? It certainly doesn't mention jQuery doing anything with the return value of the callback. Any you've done nothing to trigger the function you're passing into your plug-in in your example use. Strongly recommend stepping back, reading the API, reading through some plug-in tutorials and source code, and trying again fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edits, your code *almost* does what you mean to do. There are only a couple of problems:

1. What is the purpose of this line?

   ```
   $.item = $(this);
   ```

   You're creating a field in the jQuery object (alias `$`) that is referencing an element. If you call your plugin N times, that field will be overwritten N times. Whatever you were trying to accomplish, this is not the way to do it.
2. Your function `show` is only available inside the closure `function(callback) { ... }`, you can't access it from outside. Calling `this.show` will do nothing, and you shouldn't try to add members to `this` because it refers to a DOM element.

   For a "proper" way of doing it, I'd suggest reading some tutorials on plugin authoring, but as a quick workaround, why don't you pass the `show` function as argument to the callback also?

   ```
   $(this).hide('fast',function () {
       callback(show, 'bla');
   });

   ...

   $('form').examplePlugin(function(show, data) {
       show(data); // will perform (not return) "alert('bla')"
   });
   ```

Comment: typo: `function(show, data)) {` should be `function(show, data){`